# Any solution to filter and order on two different document properties using Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

## Issue

I am trying to filter and order on two different document properties using firestore. I am aware that in the documentation it says it is not possible. But I am confident there must be a solution perhaps on the client-side.

### Understanding

Imagine you have a bunch of articles. In these articles, there are properties such as `views` and `time`. Say I wanted to sort so I would get the most viewed article within a week. How would I create this since Firestore does not allow such a thing? Any way to handle it on the client-side or any other solution?

I know this is invalid but perhaps there would be a way to make this work:

```
admin.firestore().collection("articles").where("time", "<=", mintime).orderBy("views", "desc")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I am confident there must be a solution perhaps on the client-side.

The client side solution is to query for all possible documents, then sort them in the app instead of depending on Firestore to do that sorting for you.

Comment: Seems to be the only solution. However, if you have around 1000 articles it might be quite expensive to retrieve all those down and then continue with your sorting on client side, so I was really hoping there would be some magic trick to solving it

Comment: There is no trick.  When you have a range filter on a field in a query, you have to use that field in the sort, for performance reasons.  Firestore will not load everything into its own memory, as that would not scale in the way that Firestore requires.